# Change iframe to basic HTML <form> code

Tags: html, forms, iframe

I'm attempting to integrate a registration form widget with a landing page that does not recognise Javascript or iframe tags. It will only support basic HTML and form tags.

How can I change the iframe? I have little to no knowledge of anything but the very basics of HTML and I'm really struggling!

Thanks

```
<iframe frameborder="0" border="0" style="border: 0;height:355px; width:100%" src="my link&placeholder=1&nameOneRow=2&small=0&hidePassword=0&fb=0&facebookStyle=small&‌​hideFacebookInstruction=0&customCss=custom-widgets&css=my link.css" scrolling="no">< /iframe>
```

Comment: Post your codes please.

Comment: <iframe > frameborder="0" border="0" style="border: 0;height:355px; width:100%" src="my link&placeholder=1&nameOneRow=2&small=0&hidePassword=0&fb=0&facebookStyle=small&hideFacebookInstruction=0&customCss=custom-widgets&css=my link.css" scrolling="no">< /iframe>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the widget requires javascript, then you have to use it on the page.
The same with the iframe. You can't just simply change the iframe tag to another tag.

If you need more information about Javascript and iframes, check out these sites

iframe - [http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp)
JavaScript - [http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp](https://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp)

or you can use a site like Codecademy to learn JavaScript

I hope it help, otherwise maybe you can elaborate in why iframes and javascript isn't possible on the page:

Comment: Thank you Anders, think that was the answer I needed!